# selenium (python) click() method not working with script but working with commandline

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python 3 selenium and i want to login in https://zomato.com page but when i am writing it in a script and running it the login button got clicked but dialog box is not opening 
But when i am writing these statements in commandline(terminal) it is getting clicked and dialog box is also opening.
I have tried with chrome as well as firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/")
login_btn_outer =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*@id='signin-link']")[0].click()
```

[Dialog box not opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zZrW.png)

[dialog box opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS11g.png)

Answer (score 0):

The events are likely being applied after the page structure has loaded.
Try waiting before trying your click trigger:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/")
login_btn_outer =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*@id='signinlink']")[0].click()
```

EDIT: I took a look at the page, too. The event is applied post page ready, and  he id is `signin-link` not `signinlink` as you have.

Comment: Hey thanks for the your answer but this is giving  AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'manage' @David Crane

Comment: Sounds like you're not using an up-to-date selenium.

Try    `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`

Comment: i am using this version selenium-3.141.0 and i have tried (driver.implicitly_wait(10)) but not getting the result

Comment: I am using Selenium in python3

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This should work.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='D:/Java/TestChrome/lib/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/")
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='signin-link']")))
    element.click()
```

Let me know if this work.

Comment: Oh.let me check once again.